# Debug Facebook Instant Articles in browser

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

according to this page (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/analytics) on the Facebook Instant Articles documentation is possible to debug them in a browser using the following url:

```
 www.ia-tracker.fbsbx.com/instant_article_test?url=<share-url>
```

Now I keep getting the following error:

> Notice The trackers are run in same environment as Instant Articles,
>   except that the base url is different. On Instant article, it's the
>   url, that the user shared.

I tried to use the canonical url, without *http*, with *www* but nothing worked.

Have someone been able to use this method successfully, and if yes what they mean by "share url"?

Answer (score 1):

The debug page doesn't actually render your page in the browser, it running the tracking code it finds just like they would be run in the instant article renderer. If you open the source code of the page you will see that there is a tracker code loaded.

The purpose of that page is to test analytics code, not the FIA itself.

Basically you will have the error if you put wrong URL or if you put the URL to the article that doesn't have FIA implemented. That notice that you get is sign of successfully loaded analytics code from the FIA itself.

Comment: Is there any tool on the web to validate the article to make sure it complies.